# Render output as node output

Tags: theming

I wrote new module to scrapper some data from some websites and finally i want to show the result as a view or node page.

i used the pretty_print() for showing result which is like the warning style for drupal sites. i want to know how i could make better showing result as a block content with css setting or using theme style?

my code is :

```
    <?php
function form_example_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => t('Paper download form'), //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, // drupal's default menu type
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu', 
    'weight' => '10', // we want to display person link below in our nav menu
  );
  return $items;
}
function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
 $form['price'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => t('What is Your Price?'),
    //'#size' => 10,
    //'#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
  );
  $form['calories'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => ' '
  );
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!')
    );
     if ( $form_state['submitted'] ) {
    $form['results'] = array(
      '#value' => example_formandresults_resultstable($form_state),
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#weight' => 10, // bottom of form
    ) ;
  }


  return $form;
}

function example_formandresults_resultstable($form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Building results table.', 'status', TRUE);
  dpm($form_state, 'form state');
  $sql = "SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE login >= %d ORDER BY login";
  $qry = db_query($sql, $form_state['storage']['since']);
  while ( $uid = db_result($qry) ) {
    $account = user_load($uid);
    /* there are plenty of good examples on how to theme tables in
     * forms; this isn't one. 
     */
    $rows[] = array(
      $account->name,
      format_date($account->login),
    ) ;
  }
  // dpm($rows, 'rows');
  $headers = array( 'Name', 'Last Login' );
  $result = t("<h3>Accounts logged in since: %since</h3>", array('%since' => format_date($form_state['storage']['since']))) ;
  $result .= theme('table', $header, $rows) ;
  require_once (str_replace('\\',"/",dirname(__FILE__)).'/functions_ss.php');
$ToGo=$form_state['values']['price'] ;
$output=get_url($ToGo,'http://free-academy-paper.tk/index/?url=');
$result .=$output;

  return $result ;
}


function form_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  //if (!($form_state['values']['price'] > 0)){
  if ((preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?
                      (/.*)?$|i', $form_state['values']['price']))){

    //form_set_error('price', t('Price must be a positive number.'));

    form_set_error('price',t('PLease insert a valid address'));
  }
}


function pretty_print($data=''){
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($data,true) . '</pre>');
}

function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $ToGo='http://127.0.0.1/';
    $ToGo=$form_state['values']['price'] ;

    require_once (str_replace('\\',"/",dirname(__FILE__)).'/functions_ss.php');
    //$output = file_get_contents($ToGo); 
    //print_r($output,true);

    //$output=get_url($ToGo,'http://127.0.0.1/');
    //$output=get_url($ToGo,'http://free-academy-paper.tk/index/?url=');
    $output=get_url($ToGo,'');
    print '<div>out put is :' . $output['output']. '</div>';
    $form_state['values']['calories']=$output['output'];

    $_SESSION['form_example_data'][] = array(
        'price' => $form_state['values']['price'],
        'calories' => $form_state['values']['calories']
    );
    $form_state['render'] = TRUE;
    //pretty_print('<div>' . $output['output']. '</div>'); // to display form submitted data
      //return '<div>' . $output. '</div>';
    //$form_state['redirect'] =$output;
    //dpm($form_state, 'form state');
    print ($sid);
    //$output=get_url($ToGo,'');
    //print drupal_get_form('Click Here!', $form);
    //echo $output;
    $pdf=find_pdf($output['output'],$output['host']);

    $message='<pre> you have entered '.$form.' wich contained finded url as :'.$pdf['php'].'with size:'.$pdf['size'].'</pre>';

    //drupal_set_message(t($message));

    pretty_print($message); // to display form submitted data

    //pretty_print($form_state); // to display form submitted data
    //drupal_set_message($output['output']);
    //echo get_url('www.google.com');
    $file=get_external_file($pdf['url']);
    pretty_print($file); // to display form submitted data
    $file_path = drupal_realpath($file['uri']);
    pretty_print($file_path); // to display form submitted data
    $file_path = make_ext_url_file($file['uri']);
    pretty_print($file_path); // to display form submitted data


    if (module_exists('module_name') && function_exists('module_name_function_name')) {
        module_name_function_name();}   
    return '<div>' . $output. '</div>';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */

//return $output;
?>
```

Thanks a lot.